# Bluetooth HID server accept blocking forever

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm writing a bluetooth HID server for a small and very simple bluetooth remote. I'm following the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer).

My application's permission include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

And this is my `BluetoothServerSocket` <strike>reading</strike> connection-accepting thread:

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        while(true) {
            try {
                socket = MyBluetoothServerSocket.accept(); // problematic line
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.i(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE, e.toString());
                break;
            }
            if(socket != null) {
                readInput(socket);
                try {
                    MyBluetoothServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE, e.toString());
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE, "Could not accept a connection from the socket.\n");
            }
            break;
        }       
    }
}
```

`MyBluetoothServerSocket` is a socket constructed like this:

```
MyBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("MyService", UUID.fromString("00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
```

The UUID I'm using above is the only one my remote control device reports through the following method:

```
MyBluetoothDevice.getUuids();
```

And `MyBluetoothAdapter` is just the default adapter:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

The rest of the code involved is minimal (making sure bluetooth is on, selecting the correct device) and working correctly. The remote is *bonded* to the phone.

The line marked as problematic in the code above (`accept()`) never returns i.e. it blocks forever. What am I doing wrong?

**edit**: I've tried `MyBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord` without success.

Answer (score 0):

HID is based on the L2CAP bluetooth *profile* (protocol?), which [is not implemented](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/master/btif/src/btif_sock.c) (line 107) in Android as of October 2013.

This makes it currently impossible to connect to a HID device.